# Microsoft Graph API user search with Select & Filter condition doesn't search users with given condition

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using below code to get users with matched Display Name:

```
var users1 = await graphServiceClient.Users.Request().Select(e => new {
    e.DisplayName,
    e.GivenName,
    e.PostalCode
}).Filter($"DisplayName contains 'Robert'")
.GetAsync();
```

But ,it doesn't show any result.
I am also trying to search using wildcards or startswith i.e Filter(startswith('Robert'))
But this also doesn't work.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try following way

```
var users1 = await graphServiceClient.Users
    .Request()
    .Filter("startswith(displayName,'Robert')")
    .Select( e => new {
             e.DisplayName,
             e.GivenName
             })
    .GetAsync();
```

Please refer to [Official Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request-2) for further details.

Comment: Thanks,it works. Is wildcard search also available?

Comment: For example? Would be great if you ask a new question with your problem.

Comment: Also don't forget to mention which version of `graph SDK` you are using  because implementation varies on version.

Comment: Ok. I will ask a new question.